# Understanding Ember.Evented - how to listen on events triggered in a controller from a view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, publish-subscribe

With a controller that uses the `Ember.Evented` mixin like so:

```
    var FoosController = Ember.ArrayContoller.extend(Ember.Evented, {
        /* ... */

        actions: {
            someAction: function() {
                this.trigger('someActionMessage', 'bla bla');
            },
        },
    });
    export default FoosController;
```

I define the view that is active for this controller such that it listens
for the `someActionMessage`, like so:

```
    var FoosView = Ember.View.extend({
        onSomeActionMessage: function() {
            console.log('FoosView onSomeActionMessage', arguments);
        }.on('controller.someActionMessage'),
    });
    export default FoosView;
```

... However, the `onSomeActionMessage` method never gets called.
So I try something else, which seems equivalent, except more verbose (and messier).

```
    var FoosView = Ember.View.extend({
        onDidInsertElement: function() {
            var ctrl = this.get('controller');
            ctrl.on('someActionMessage', this, this.onSomeActionMessage);
        }.on('didInsertElement'),

        onSomeActionMessage: function() {
            console.log('FoosView onSomeActionMessage', arguments);
        },
    });
    export default FoosView;
```

This, on the other hand, works as expected.

Why does the latter work, but not the former;
why doesn't `.on()` work for my custom event like it does for `didInsertElement`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `on` supports chaining.  Hence it isn't able to chain to the controller and its event.  That's why when you manually set it up, and just pass in the event name it properly works.  That's how I originally understood it, I'd need to go watch the code work, but I'm fairly certain that's how it was designed.

Comment: kingpin2k what do you mean by chaining here? The latter method, which works, is the one where chaining occurs, where one `.on()` is registered within another function that is itself `.on()`. It appears that the variant *without* chaining is the one that does not work. Am I understanding you right?

Comment: sorry, when I say chaining I'm referring to the chaining that occurs on a get/set/property ( this.get('foo.bar') is essentially this.get('foo').get('bar'), translated into a chain of gets/sets).  So when you attempt to set up a "chained event" `controller.someEvent`  Ember doesn't actually setup up the chain, and follow the controller back to its event.  (hopefully this wasn't more confusing, it's getting late)